# Esiste la parola “rotolacampo”?

Tags: single-words

Vedo che qualcuno usa la parola “rotolacampo” per designare quei cespugli rotolanti tipici di certe atmosfere semidesertiche americane (i *tumbleweed*, in inglese). Ma esiste veramente, questa parola?

Ovviamente, visto che c'è chi la usa, la risposta da un certo punto di vista è senz'altro “sì”, ma:

- non la trovo su nessun dizionario (ha una voce sulla Wikipedia italiana, ma questo significa solo che qualcuno ci si è messo e l'ha fatta);
- in Google Books ne trovo <strike>tre occorrenze in tutto, e tutte e tre in traduzioni</strike> poche occorrenze, per lo più in traduzioni;
- in rete Google ne dà <strike>350</strike> circa 1500 occorrenze in tutto, che è un numero bassissimo, minore di quello ottenuto per esempio prendendo una parola qualsiasi e scrivendola in modo sbagliato: “sbaliato” ne dà alcune migliaia (non sto dicendo che “rotolacampo” sia una parola sbagliata; sto solo dicendo che compare pochissimo in rete).

Qualcuno sa se questa parola è attestata in qualche senso (usata da qualche “addetto ai lavori”, riportata da qualche opera di consultazione affidabile) o chi l'ha coniata?

Comment: C'è la voce in [it.wikipedia.org](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotolacampo). Mai sentito prima.

Comment: Grazie, @egreg, avevo menzionato la Wikipedia italiana, e anche il mio scetticismo per il suo valore come fonte.

Comment: Penso che questa pianta si chiami [steppicursore](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/steppicursore/) perché è originaria della steppa russa.

Comment: Io la uso normalmente e senza nessun problema di comprensione da parte degli ascoltanti.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Su Google Books trovo molto più di tre occorrenze, anche se pur sempre poche: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=p&hl=it&q=rotolacampo

Esiste un racconto di Čechov che si chiama proprio "Rotolacampo", ovvero è stato tradotto così in un'edizione del 1996 curata da Fausto Malcovati per Garzanti. Questo significa che la parola gira in ambito letterario almeno da vent'anni ed è stata ripresa da altri libri, tra cui la traduzione di "Infinite Jest" e se Google Books non mi inganna anche un Benni e un Baricco.

La voce su Wikipedia è stata creata da un utente anonimo nel 2009, da un indirizzo IP che ha scritto solo la bozza di quella pagina, il che non milita a suo favore. So che Wikipedia è usata spesso dai traduttori per parole insolite come *tumbleweed* quindi in effetti questo potrebbe essere stato un canale non secondario per la diffusione di questa traduzione.

Resta il fatto che così stando le cose si potrebbe ben dire che la parola esiste, in fondo non esiste quella pianta in Italia o a Nizza o nel Canton Ticino quindi a decidere originariamente il modo "giusto" di chiamarla è proprio la ristretta comunità dei traduttori e a sdoganarla è l'uso, in primo luogo degli scrittori. Dubito che i botanici la chiamino così.

Comment: Giusto, Mauro! Chissà che pasticcio avevo fatto cercando su Google Books: modifico lievemente la domanda. Grazie mille per le segnalazioni (anche se temo che Benni e Baricco siano falsi positivi, perché andando a cercare specificamente nei libri la parola sembra non esserci). Mi rimane la curiosità, per un termine così recente, di capire chi l'abbia coniato e perché in questo modo bizzarro (quasi che “rotolare” fosse transitivo).

Comment: @DaG: È curioso però che nel Treccani appaia "steppicursore" (parola simile a quelle usate in catalano e in castigliano) e non "rotolacampo".

Comment: Ah ecco, sono falsi positivi Benni e Barrico? Come l'hai scoperto? Io non riesco a capire se è Books che non mi mostra le pagine specifiche per una questione di copyright o se è sempre Books che sbaglia a mettermeli tra i risultati. In entrambi i casi, buuu(ks)!

Answer (score 6):

L'ottima risposta di @MauroVanetti mi ha spinto ad approfondire il titolo del racconto di Čechov, e sospetto che il termine “rotolacampo” venga proprio da una resa letterale del corrisponde termine russo.

Delle edizioni che ho, quella BUR tradotta da Alfredo Polledro del 1953 titola il racconto «Ruzzola-campi», mentre in quella Sansoni del 1966 questo racconto è tradotto da Giovanni Faccioli col titolo «Granello errante», ma una nota spiega «è stato sostituito il titolo russo *Perekatì-pole*, letteralmente “rotolacampo”, nome popolare di una pianta spinosa che cresce nella steppa (in latino *eryngium campestre*), così chiamata perché, quando è secca, il vento la strappa via e la fa rotolare per i campi, spesso a grandi distanze».

Amici russi aggiungono che in realtà il termine non designa una sola ben precisa specie vegetale, e in più si usa figuratamente anche per designare un vagabondo.

Comment: Bel colpo! Ma non capisco bene la nota: è stato sostituito cosa con cosa?